# Rails, align dynamic elements using bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my products display view and align them using bootstrap, like in my model.
The problem is that, because elements are create dynamically, I can' t do a big bootstap div for all my elements, in order to set an offset, and if I just set my elem size, they are no aligned at all : [image]
I displayed them with black background to see better how each div is positioned.

```html
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="entry col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
      <div class="product_img img-responsive">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
      </div>
    <div class="product_description">
      <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
      <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my model is : [image]

How can I do please?

Edit: My problem is not resolved yet, I always have my elems going everywhere, I did two sections and they do not react the same.. I really do not understand what is the problem actually.. Is it possible that rails do not supports well Bootstrap?
Here is my code actually, I changed it a little..

```css
.logo_img{
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  left: -50px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

 .title{
   display: block;
  top: 100px;
}

.img_tasse{
  top: 100px;
  left : -60px;
  max-width: 110px;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  left: -50px;
top : 190px;
}

.img_back{
  z-index: 1;
  top: 170px;
  left : 0;
}

.illu_front{

  top: -410px;
  z-index: 2;
}

p.txt_soli{
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -760px;
}

.soli{
  background-color: blue;
}

.entry{
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top : -200px;
  text-align: left;
}

.product_img{
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.the_img{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
    width: 15vw;
    max-width: 250px;
}

.the_img:hover + .discover{
  display: block;
}

.the_img + .discover:hover{
  display: block;
  color: black;

}

.the_img:hover{
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.prod{
  background-color: black;
  margin-right : 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.discover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vw;
  left: 2.5vw;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.line_title{
  position: relative;
}

#fade { /*--Masque opaque noir de fond--*/
 display: none; /*--masqué par défaut--*/
 background: #000;
 position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
 opacity: .80;
 z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block{
 display: none; /*--masqué par défaut--*/
 background: #fff;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 20px solid #ddd;
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 z-index: 99999;
 /*--Les différentes définitions de Box Shadow en CSS3--*/
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
 /*--Coins arrondis en CSS3--*/
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
img.btn_close {
 float: right;
 margin: -40px -30px 0 0;
}
/*--Gérer la position fixed pour IE6--*/

a:hover{
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="product_section_1">
  <header id="top" class="header-store">
    <div class="img-top container">
      <a href="/showcase/Home"> <p><%=image_tag("logo.png", :class => 'logo_img col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-3 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-5')%></p></a>
      <p class="title col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5"> nos collections</p>
            <div class="img_tasse col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-6"><%=image_tag("tasse-section-1.png")%></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-sultan container">
      <h1 class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-4 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-5 line_title">Les infusions du Sultan</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img_back col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1"><%=image_tag("photo-back-section-1.png")%></div>
        <div class="illu_front col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-7 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-7 col-md-4 col-md-offset-7 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-7"><%=image_tag("illu-front-section-1.png")%></div>
      </div>
      <p class="txt_soli col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2"> le roi preferé des francais, François 1er fut connu pour son amour de l'élegance, du raffinement et de la culture. Contemporain
      de Soliman, ils établirent ensemble les premières relations diplomatiques au monde.</p>
  </div>
</header>
  <div class="row prod">
    <% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
    <% @type1.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="product-tile">
        <div class="entry col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col">
          <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
          <div class="product_img img-responsive">
            <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
            <%= link_to 'Discover', '#', class: %w(poplight discover), data: { rel: "popup_type1#{index}", width: "1000"} %>
              <div id="popup_type1<%= index %>" class="popup_block">
                <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
                 <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
                  <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
                  <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
                 <p>Soh Tanaka est traduit sur developpez.com.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product_description">
            <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
            <div class="price_line">
              <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="product_section_2">
  <header id="top" class="header-store">
    <div class="img-top container">
      <div class="img_tasse col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-6"><%=image_tag("tasse-section-2.png")%></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-sultan container">
      <h1 class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-4 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-5 line_title">Les infusions du Roi</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img_back col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1"><%=image_tag("photo-back-section-2.jpg")%></div>
        <div class="illu_front col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-7 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-7 col-md-4 col-md-offset-7 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-7"><%=image_tag("illu-front-section-2.jpg")%></div>
      </div>
      <p class="txt_soli col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2"> le roi preferé des francais, François 1er fut connu pour son amour de l'élegance, du raffinement et de la culture. Contemporain
      de Soliman, ils établirent ensemble les premières relations diplomatiques au monde.</p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="row prod">
    <% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
    <% @type2.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="product-tile">
        <div class="entry col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col">
          <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
          <div class="product_img img-responsive">
            <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
            <%= link_to 'Discover', '#', class: %w(poplight discover), data: { rel: "popup_type2#{index}", width: "1000"} %>
              <div id="popup_type2<%= index %>" class="popup_block">
                <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
                 <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
                 <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
                 <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
                 <%= text_field_tag 'quantity' %>
                 <p>Soh Tanaka est traduitee sur developpez.com.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product_description">
            <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
            <div class="price_line">
              <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want my elems to be aligned by 3, and when the screen is not large enough, I want them to me aligned by 2.. How Would you do that?
Pehaps that there is a conflict with an other css, like scaffold.scss but I didn't found where I could be.
I hope someone may found the problem. Thanks..

Comment: Is there a way I could get access to the code(github repo)?

Comment: Yes, I pushed it on my github repo, you'll find in in the "work" folder here, thank you! : https://github.com/lennonmarley/42school/tree/master/work/depot_recent

Comment: Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the changing heights. If your text is constantly varying, try consider truncating it with ellipsis and then showing more on the show page.

To fix the problem with your current page, I'd make a wrapper for everything in a div and give it a fixed height. EG:

```
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product-tile">
      <div class="entry col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
        <div class="product_img img-responsive">
          <%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
        </div>
      <div class="product_description">
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
          <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Then give the `product-tile` css a height of say `height: 400px`, or you play with and work out.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this fix but the problem is the same, my elems are displayed like stairs, not on the same horizontal line..

Comment: It finally worked, I can't believe that you gave me the good answer so long time ago..  I didn't pay attention of the part about the text changing height.. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to fit too many columns into a row.  Try starting with this and then you can style the divs as you like.

```
<% @products.in_groups_of(3, false) do |products| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-xs-4 ...">
        ...
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked at all, elems were placed one by one with this trick

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to do with the 3 loops nested inside each other?  `<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
    <% @type1.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %`

Comment: I found that trick on the Pragprog book to show the database cache content.. I shouldn't do that? do you thing this cause issues?